# Play Console: How does "Internal Test Track" work after completing Review?

Tags: android, release-management, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I intend to distribute my app for testing to a specific list of users.

I have setup all that is required to be able to 'publish' for testing. I then went in `App Releases` > `Internal Test Track` and all the way to review.

I now have a screen as below and am not sure what to click on next.

`Create Release` seems to just take me to the same Internal Test Track setup, for another test release.

I'm not sure of clicking on `Release to Alpha` as that was another option inside `App Release` so I'm guessing thats a level higher than `Internal testing`

**Should I wait for a few hours** before the specified users can see the app in the play store, **or is there some other step to take from here**?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the main menu, under `All applications` the summarised list of apps shows their status; in my case status is `Pending publication`.

It's been about 3 hours since I submitted, and research suggests that if it is the first time uploading, it will take longer, 3+ hours, no guarantee on length.

[image]

Some people seem to [experience days of waiting](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/12354058?hl=en).

**Update 1**

It's been `20 hours` now, still in `Pending Publication`

**Update 2**

App has finally been approved after about 2days 18hours.

A further submission after that took less than an hour.